# Aspect around call on annotated field

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, aspect

I want AspectJ to inject the measuring code around all invocations of any method, on fields annotated with @Measured and capture the method's name.
This is what I have:

```
@Pointcut("get(@my.annotation.Measured * *) && @annotation(measured)")
public void fieldAnnotatedWithMeasured(Measured measured) {}

@Around(value = "fieldAnnotatedWithMeasured(measured)", argNames = "joinPoint,measured")
public Object measureField(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Measured measured) throws Throwable {...}
```

Use case:

```
public class A { 

  @Measured private Service service;
  ...
  void call(){
    service.call(); // here I want to measure the call() time and capture its name
  }
```

This seems to surround only the access to the field, not the method invocation. I want to capture the invoked method name instide the advise.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can do directly with a pointcut because `get()`, as you have noticed, is entirely different from `call()` or `execution()` pointcuts. The `get()` joinpoint has completely passed before the moment the `call()` is done. Furthermore, the `call()` has no idea about whether or not the target object it is called upon happens to be assigned to one or more (annotated) class members.

I think that what you want to achieve is conceptually problematic. You should rather annotate the classes or methods you want to measure, not class members. But for what it is worth, I am going to present you with a solution. Caveat: The solution involves manual bookkeeping and also reflection. Thus, it is kinda slow but maybe still fast enough for your purpose. You can decide if you give it a try. Please note that this solution is something I feel uneasy with because it does not feel like a good application of AOP.

Okay, so here is our test setup:

**Field annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Measured {}
```

**Sample class to play around with later:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class MyClass {
    private String name;

    public MyClass(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass[" + name + "]";
    }

    void waitForAWhile() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
}
```

**Driver application using the sample class:**

Please note how only two of the four members - one primitive and one object type - are annotated by `@Measured` and two others are not. I did this in order to have positive as well as negative examples so as to see whether the aspect works correctly.

Another important thing is that an object formerly assigned to an annotated class member should no longer be reported by the aspect as soon as it is no longer assigned to that member. I.e. `oldMyClass.waitForAWhile();` should not be measured.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    String foo = "unmeasured";
    @Measured String bar = "measured";
    MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass("unmeasured");
    @Measured MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass("measured");

    void doSomething() throws InterruptedException {
        foo.length();
        bar.length();
        myClass1.waitForAWhile();
        myClass2.waitForAWhile();

        MyClass oldMyClass = myClass2;
        myClass2 = new MyClass("another measured");
        // This call should not be reported by the aspect because the object
        // is no longer assigned to a member annotated by @Measured
        oldMyClass.waitForAWhile();
        // This call should be reported for the new member value
        myClass2.waitForAWhile();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Application().doSomething();
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

The aspect takes care of two things: bookkeeping and measuring. In detail:

- Whenever a value gets assigned to a `@Measured` field, it is recorded in a set of `measuredObjects` because this is the only way to later know that when a method is called on that object, it really should be measured.
- While it is easy to get hold of the new value in a `before() : set()` advice, unfortunately there is no straightforward way to get hold of the old value. This is why we need the ugly little helper method `getField(Signature signature)` using reflection in order to find out.
- Why do we need the old value anyway? Because in order to have clean bookkeeping we have to remove unassigned objects from the `measuredObjects` set.
- Please also note that `measuredObjects` is not thread-safe the way I implemented it, but you can just use a synchronized collection if you need that.
- The `call()` advice first checks if it can find the target object in `measuredObjects` and stops executing if it cannot. Otherwise it measures the method call's runtime. This is straightforward.

Oh, and by the way, I am using the cleaner and more expressive native AspectJ syntax here, not the ugly annotation style. If you have any problems with that, please let me know.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;
import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;

import de.scrum_master.app.Measured;

public aspect MyAspect {
    private Set<Object> measuredObjects = new HashSet<>(); 
    
    before(Measured measured, Object newValue, Object object) :
        set(* *) &&
        @annotation(measured) &&
        args(newValue) &&
        target(object) 
    {
        try {
            Field field = getField(thisJoinPoint.getSignature()); 
            Object oldValue = field.get(object); 
            System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
            System.out.println("  old value = " + oldValue);
            System.out.println("  new value = " + newValue);
            measuredObjects.remove(oldValue);
            measuredObjects.add(newValue);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SoftException(e);
        }
    }
    
    Object around(Object object) :
        call(* *(..)) &&
        target(object) &&
        !within(MyAspect)
    {
        if (!measuredObjects.contains(object))
            return proceed(object);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Object result = proceed(object);
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("  object   = " + object);
        System.out.println("  duration = " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1e6 + " ms");
        return result;
    }

    private Field getField(Signature signature) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        Field field = signature.getDeclaringType().getDeclaredField(signature.getName());
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field;
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
set(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.bar)
  old value = null
  new value = measured
set(MyClass de.scrum_master.app.Application.myClass2)
  old value = null
  new value = MyClass[measured]
call(int java.lang.String.length())
  object   = measured
  duration = 0.080457 ms
call(void de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.waitForAWhile())
  object   = MyClass[measured]
  duration = 200.472326 ms
set(MyClass de.scrum_master.app.Application.myClass2)
  old value = MyClass[measured]
  new value = MyClass[another measured]
call(void de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.waitForAWhile())
  object   = MyClass[another measured]
  duration = 200.461208 ms
```

As you can see, the aspect behaves correctly. It only reports the method call on object `MyClass[measured]` once, while it is assigned to a `@Measured` field, but not when a method is called upon it after it has already been unassigned and replaced by `MyClass[another measured]`. The latter is correctly reported subsequently. You also see how the aspect works beautifully even for primitives like the String `"measured"`.

Enjoy!

---

**Update 2021-04-22:** I found this old answer again and wanted to mention a few other problems with the sample code, in addition to thread-unsafety:

- The `Set<Object> measuredObjects` does not account for the fact that the same object can be assigned to multiple fields. If we want to consider that, we need to map a unique combination of instance and field to the corresponding value, i.e. we would need some kind of `Map<Field,<Map<Object, Object>>` where in the nested map the key is the instance (or the class name for static fields) and the value is the current field value. Managing this kind of data structure would be more complicated than the simple set we have now, especially if we also want to remove entries after a value is being unassigned.
- Currently we use a simple `HashSet`. Actually, that is incorrect, because normal sets check for object value equality, not object identity. I.e. we could have conflicting instances `a` and `b`, where `a.equals(b)`, but `a != b`. In order to fix that, we need an `IdentitySet` or, with the improvement I suggested in the first bullet point, an `IdentityMap`.
- Considering the preceding two bullet points, probably a better alternative would be a dedicated class `MeasuredEntity` with fields `Field field`, `Object instance`, `Object value` and correctly defined `equals` and `hashCode` methods. then we could use a simple hash set again in order to do the bookkeeping.
- Caveat: One problem cannot be solved by any kind of AspectJ-based bookeeping: If an object is currently assigned to any `@Measured` field, say `A.x`, then of course the measuring advice will get triggered if you call `A.x.doSomething()`. But there is no way of knowing if the same object is assigned to a non-measured field `B.y` or a local variable `myLocal` at the same time. So if `B.y.doSomething()` or `myLocal.doSomething()` are called, the measuring advice will also fire, which might be OK or unintended, depending on your individual situation. I think that it is no problem, you just need to be aware of it.
- References to instances are not being removed from the set or map if an instance goes out of scope and would otherwise be eligible for garbage collection. In order to achieve that, we would need to use weak references.
- A smaller issue is that `getField(..)` uses `field.setAccessible(true)`. We might want to reset the field's accessible state after use in some kind of `try {} finally {}`, first storing the original value in a `boolean` variable, then resetting it in the `finally` block. But if that does not bother you, it really is just a small issue and also makes code execution a bit slower when called often.

Conclusion: Manual bookkeeping is not just complicated but in practice also poses several challenges which are difficult to fully meet. Not walking this path in the first place and changing the application design instead, so as to be able to apply aspects without recording internal object state, effectively breaking class encapsulation, is the better alternative IMO.

Comment: **Update 2021-04-22:** Please note that I have just updated the answer with some new considerations.